# Issue adding an app to django admin and displaying the models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am new on django and I have a very basic project with the following structure

```
[django_test
├── django_test
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── current_age.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
├── my_app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt][1]
```

I have ran my project and I got something as  the initial django admin screen

But as you can see I have inside the project an app called my_app and inside the my_app's path I have a models file with some models as Model1, Model2, Model3 in other django projects I have seen than in other in the dashboard you have access  to your models for to added, deleted, consulted and edited from there.

Which addtional step am I missing ?

Comment: Can you clarify more what you saw vs. what you expected to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is wath you are looking for but let's try:
I think you have installed django.contrib.admin in your INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file, this is why you are able to see a dashboard, for to add models to that dashboard you just need to edit the admin.py file for the app tha you wnat to add to the dashboard, in this case my_app.admin.py in that file you should import the models and register it, something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Foo, Bar, Baz


admin.site.register(Foo)
admin.site.register(Bar)
admin.site.register(Baz)
```

after that you should see a section with the app's name and the published models in the dasboard

I hope it's usefull for you, otherwise please provide more details, mayben adding an image about how do you want to display your dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

You should register your models into admin:

**my_app/admins.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models


admin.site.register(models.Model1)
# and for other models as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Include your app with `INSTALLED_APPS` in **settings.py** and register your app in **admin.py** ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/)):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

admin.site.register(models.YourModelName)
```